# WPF - Image source with MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, image, imagesource

In WPF, How to use Image source with Multi:

```
<Image x:Name="imgLane1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="25" Margin="180,225,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Stretch="Fill">
                                        <Image.Source>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="StaticResource LaneImageConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                                <Binding Path="Attachments">
                                                <Binding Path="Delivery"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Image.Source>
                                    </Image>`
 public class LaneImageConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = "";
        int attachments = 0;
        string delivery = values[1].ToString();
        Int32.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out attachments);
        return System.Windows.Data.Binding.DoNothing;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I can not update imageSource with MultiBinding also debug to update source
Please help me ?

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` on a OneWay Binding is pointless. You should remove it.

Comment: I removed it. I still can not set breakpoint after run my app. You can see the image: https://imgur.com/a/UJiaE1n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converter must return an instance of a class that is derived from `ImageSource`, e.g. a `BitmapImage` that is loaded from the path of an image file:

```
public object Convert(
    object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string path = "";
    // compose path from values

    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
}
```

When the image file is an assembly resource, you would use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf):

```
var uri = string.Format("pack://application:,,,/images/{0}{1}.png", values); // for example

return new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
```

Comment: I tried. But seem not work with new URi.I cant not set debug in code-behind

Comment: Do you mean you can't set a breakpoint? You should also tell us more about the images you want to show. Are there image files with certain paths you want to load?

Comment: I'm sure that I set a breakpoint. 
I have a folder "Images", same with file: xaml and xaml.cs. I want to show the image source such as "Images/11.png in that 1: first Binding, and 1: second Binding.
Anything about my bug ?

Comment: What is your bug? Your question asks how to write the converter. This answer shows how. If your converter isn't called, it's probably the properties that don't fire a change notification.

Comment: My bug is not that can not created image source when create new BItmapImage